# ball detection in python runs very slow, any tips on impoving it?

Tags: python, computer-vision

I am working on a sensor for PID controler, so basically I have a camera recording a scene. In order for control to work I need to extract tennis ball's position on a scene in each frame. Scene is set with white background and orange tennis ball as you can see on image:
[image]

And when I run it on my lenovo ideapad 100 (which is quite slow pc) I get ball's position each let's say 1.2 secs.
I think this could be done way faster but I don't know what to do.
Any tips and suggestions are welcome.

Im expecting a system that can generate at least 2 position each second

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
lower_red = np.array([0,100,100])
upper_red = np.array([20,255,255])

while(1): 
    start = time.time()
    # Load an color image in grayscale

    _,img = cap.read()
    print("read")
    #get the image's width and height
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (11, 11), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    hsv2 = cv2.cvtColor(blurred,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv2, lower_red, upper_red)
    mask2 = cv2.erode(mask2, None, iterations=2)
    mask2 = cv2.dilate(mask2, None, iterations=2)

    imageWidth = mask2.shape[1]
    imageHeight = mask2.shape[0]

    sum_i_white = 1
    num_white = 1
    sum_j_white = 1
    for i in range(0,imageHeight):
        for j in range(0,imageWidth):
            if mask2[i][j] == 255:
                sum_i_white += i
                sum_j_white += j
                num_white += 1

    cv2.circle(img,(int(sum_j_white/num_white),int(sum_i_white/num_white)),3,(0,0,255), -1)
    cv2.putText(img,'here',(int(sum_j_white/num_white),int(sum_i_white/num_white)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (0,0,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.imshow("final",img)
    print(time.time()-start)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what is slow?
I know you can run C program with Python.
So, if your double for is very slow, you can make a C program running this.
If you have juste array and int as input, and int as output, I think it shouldn't be hard.
But I don't know if this would be useful.